# How to show Nested charts Radar chart within Doughnut Chart?

Tags: angular, chart.js, bar-chart, pie-chart, radar-chart

I am trying to render **Radar chart** in **Doughnut chart** using *[image: Chart.js]* and **angular** framework. I have tried using CSS transform and layout padding property of charts.
But I know this is not the proper way to do it. Then I tried to use chart within chart for **Doughnut chart** and it was so easy just need to add second array in the array of dataset that look like attach image. I need to render **radar chart** in middle of chart which is empty now. you can check my desired graph too in 2nd image.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Charts behave differently than other elements in the sense that they do not order themselves according to css properties, but rather in the order in which they were created (this is also true for all svg / canvas elements).

So, please check if both elements are being created. If they are, render the outer edge first, then render the inner afterwards.

If not please share a little bit more on why you think it doesn't work and what you have tried.

Good luck on this!